# SQL can handle AM but no a.m

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a problem with a database. I'm using SQL Server 2008. A table in the database does have a column to store the time, but since it depends on the windows configuration on client computer, I have records that look like these

```
id|date     |time
1 | 1/1/2013| 3:05:43 PM
2 | 1/1/2013| 3:06:33 PM
3 | 1/1/2013| 4:05:54 PM
4 | 1/1/2013| 7:04:41 PM
5 | 1/1/2013| 3:25:43 p.m.
6 | 1/1/2013| 3:16:33 p.m.
7 | 1/1/2013| 4:55:54 p.m.
8 | 1/1/2013| 7:04:41 p.m.
```

And I'm using this

```
convert(varchar, cast([time] as datetime),108)
```

I have tested a query and it only works with records ending with PM, but results on an error when the query includes a record ending with p.m.

Since it is already implemented software it would be easier to handle this the way it is stored in the database, than use a full datetime data type to store both date and time.

Comment: Why not store in DateTime field and only *present* to user according to configuration on client computer? How is alternative easier? Is it easier to implement more hacks and workarounds for every possible configuration?

Comment: I cant modify database, and historical data is already in this incorrect way of handling datetime,that's why i'm trying to use a convert to the stored records. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In an ideal world you could change the way they are stored to use a proper `DATETIME`, but since that isn't an option you could add a `REPLACE()` in there:

```
SELECT CAST(REPLACE([time],'.','') AS TIME)
FROM Table1
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a802f/6/0)

If needing the `CONVERT()`:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),CAST(REPLACE([time],'.','') AS TIME),108)
FROM Table1
```

Comment: Awesome !! 

Just in case someone asking the same question, the datatype time does not exist in sql server 2008, datetime is the one that should be used.

CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),CAST(REPLACE([time],'.','') AS DATETIME),108) 

Thanks.

Comment: @PhraTankian checkoff the answer to mark it as answered if it worked

Comment: I thought `TIME` was added in 2008.  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677243(v=sql.100).aspx